# Use many to many relation on indexQuery in Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I try to figure out how I can filter the results in Laravel Nova, specifically on the **indexQuery** method.

I have the following tables:

- Projects *(Id, Title)*
- Users *(Id, Name, ...)*
- Projects_Users *(Project_Id, User_Id)*

So on my Projects Resource I'd like to return only the **Projects** which belong to the currently logged in **User**.

I thought maybe this code would work, but it doesn't.

```
/**
 * Build an "index" query for the given resource.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public static function indexQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $user_id = $request->user()->id;
    return $query->whereRelation('projects_users', 'user_id', '=', $user_id);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: You might be able to get it working with something like this:
Users::whereHas('projects_users', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
});

Comment: Thanks! I only worry that when other things like filtering are in place, I need to start from the actual $query (Query Builder) which holds that information. So $query is actually a Query Builder.